# Who was the person who fired the Xindi weapon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

Who was the pilot that fired the Xindi weapon at earth? I am sure I remember a episode where they mention his name.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Xindi_incident

Comment: He was a Xindi-Reptilian, but as far as I can recall, that was all we learn about him.

Comment: @Richard your probably right, but I could have sworn they mentioned a name at some point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Reptilian pilot's name was not mentioned.

A Xindi-Reptilian had piloted the weapon to Earth, but he was not named:

> **CMDR. DOLIM:** There's a reason reptilians are called upon when force must be applied. It was a reptilian who piloted the weapon that attacked your world.
>
> **ARCHER:** Friend of yours?
>
> **CMDR. DOLIM:** He was from my regiment. I selected him myself.
>
> **ARCHER:** You must be very proud.
>
> **CMDR. DOLIM:** His name will go down in history. It will be spoken with reverence, a testament to the superiority of the cold-blooded.
>
> **ARCHER:** I'll bet you didn't know this, but at one time most of my world was ruled by reptiles.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/70.htm))

Since Dolim asserted, *"**His name** will go down in history..."*, you may be falsely recalling that his name was explicitly mentioned.